# Do Google's Protocol Buffers automatically align data efficiently?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

In a typical C or C++ `struct` the developer must explicitly order data members in a way that provides efficient memory alignment and padding, if that is an issue.

Google's Protocol Buffers behave a lot like `struct`s and it is not clear how the compilation of these affects memory layout. Does anyone know if this tendency to organize data in a specific order for the sake of efficient memory layout is automatically handled by the protocol buffer compiler? I have been unable to find any information on this.

I.E. the buffer might actually internally order the data differently than it is specified in the `message` object of the protobuf.

Comment: I removed the C# and protobuf-net tags, because I don't believe the question is applicable to those. Interesting question, though

Comment: @MarcGravell actually protobuffs are in fact used in c# and .net regularly, so that is why I added those tags

Comment: Err, protobufs are a wire format, not a memory format. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: It does not do this.  I tried sending a set of fields with a large blob of bytes.  The blob of bytes is not always word aligned relative to the beginning of the protobuf message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a typical C or C++ struct the developer must explicitly order data members in a way that provides efficient memory alignment and padding, if that is an issue.

Actually this is not entirely true.

It's true that most compilers (actually all I know of) tend to align struct elements to machine word addresses. They do this, due to performance reasons because it's usually cheaper to read from a word address and just mask away some bits than to read from the word address, shift the word, so the value you are looking for is right aligned and the mask away the bits not needed. (Of course this depends on the architecture you are compiling for)

So why is your statement I quoted above not true? - Because of the fact that compilers are arranging elements as described above, they also offer the programmer the opportunity to influnece this behavior. Usually this is done using a compiler specific pragma.

For example GCC and MS C Compilers provide a [pragma called "pack"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) which allows the programmer to change the alignment behavior of the compiler for specific structs. Of course, if you choose to set pack to '1', the memory usage is improvide, but this will possibly impact your runtime behavior.

What never happens to my knowledge is a reordering of the members in a struct by the compiler.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why I wonder how the data structure of a google protobuf, which is a binary format designed for efficiency, rearranges members thereby improving the experience for the developer and offering one of the advantages of using a protobuf.

Comment: @OpenLearner protocol buffers is sort of a generic container format to push information back and forth. This is parsed and generated using the protocol buffers libraries. After parsing the received blob, there is no relationship between the structure of the data on the wire and the structure you have in memory. So I'm afraid I didn't get your question ...

Comment: Google's protocol buffers seem to be accessible without creating your own additional runtime structure, so I don't understand your comment. I'm referring to the layout of the data in memory when a compiled protocol buffer is loaded by a program. You can directly access the contents of the buffer.

Comment: @OpenLearner Actually you create an additional runtime structure by using the core libraries. The class files you create using `protoc` only contain the message specific code that is needed to read the attributes of the message out of the stream and place them into the class fields. That's exactly the benefit of using protobufs: You won't ever get in touch with the "wire Format". So the data you can "access directly" is always already parsed by the core runtime and the message object and placed in the memory properly layouted.